# windows 7 fails to install to raid 0

Tags: windows-7, raid

I recently purchased 2 120gb ocz ssd's and my goal is to install windows 7 64 bit to them in a raid 0 array. What I've ended up with is 2 computers torn apart, my tv disabled, a bleeding thumb and no sleep in the last 24 hours (its a long story).

Im using ich9r to manage the array and I made sure sata was set to raid in the bios. Using intels interface during the boot I created a raid 0 array. My machine boots to the windows install disk and i see the array as a single drive as expected. For good measure i load the raid drivers from a usb stick and procede with the install. It looks like it finishes the first phase before the restart and then restarts. It then restarts and when the  raid drives are listed (the place where you can hit ctrl i to setup your raid) it shows one of the drives as "error occurred"

I also had another scenario where i did the same thing minus loading the driver and it got to the point in the install where it continues after the first reboot but then partway through i got bsod.